# Transformation of files

Tags: .net, transformation

we have the following problem. We have several sorts of documents (txt, xsl) to transform them into output files (txt) accordingly to some rules. Now it's done by stupid hardcoding but we prefer to use some templates or rules-defining files (in xml format for example). The problem is we have assumption that creating of this files (those with rules) can be the difficult and tricky. Maybe there is some tool or API or something like that to make it easier? Or/and maybe there is some tool for doing of this kind of transformation?

The using platform is .NET 4.0.

Comment: Can you please post examples of what you are talking about? All this abstract discussion is difficult to understand and impossible to offer a solution for.

Comment: We have the input document. It can be txt or xsl. We should transform it into output format. We know for example that first 10 bytes of input doc should be placed in output file from 21 to 31 bytes etc. So the problem we have a lot of rules and our program now just hardcodes them but it's bad if the rules were changed, right? So we prefer to have some kind of rules that our program could understand and do transformation accordingly to them. So it the rules are changed we can change the rules in this template but not the code.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want to do is abstract out a document structure that is generic and captures all of the details from all of the formats that you want to translate to/from.  This generic format could be XML or something else.

Then your problem is reduced to translating all formats to the generic format, and translating the generic format to all of the other formats.

Developing these sets of specific methods can be aided further by either code generation (that creates the hardcoded methods for you from a template) or by abstrating out the parse methods further and expressing the rules for a particular document type more as metadata, which drives which specific functions you call.

Comment: Not sure that we need some generic format. Because the data in several kinds of documents can be different. Maybe inside we can use something like dictionary to load data from input doc to, and then put them into the output doc accordingly to the rules-defining file. We can generate parse methods as you said but how to maintain the rule-defining file (template)?

Answer (score 0):

You might check out the [Text Transformer](http://www.texttransformer.com/) tool.

I've looked at this tool and it seems like it would, but I have no specific experience with it.